# libgit2sharp Get different files between branches ignoring what a merge would deal with

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I'm using a tool TFS, when performing a pull request it will tell you the files and differences that would need to be merged. 
With Libgit2sharp (I thought) I was doing the same using the command:

```
string mergeIntoReleaseBranch = "Release_XYZ";
string branchToBeMerged = "MyFeature1";
TreeChanges treeChanges = repository.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(repository.Branches[mergeIntoReleaseBranch].Tip.Tree, repository.Branches[branchToBeMerged].Tip.Tree);
```

However I sometimes see that libgit2sharp will return many more differences than TFS.  TFS is removing items that would be automatically merged. I can remove these extra items by merging in the release branch into my feature (`git checkout MyFeature1 ; git merge Release_XYZ ; git push`) then re-running the libgit2sharp code.

How can I get a list of files that would need to be merged given two branches; removing items that would automatically be merged. (and Does that take some knowledge of how TFS is doing things behind the scenes?)

Comment: This seems related https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/checking-out-visual-studio-online-pull-requests-locally.html

Comment: I can sort of shed more light on the question.. TFS is showing a diff between the would be code (left side) and the lastest? branch (right side merged into) That checksum of the would be branch isn't available. You can get it, perhaps in multiple ways but what I found is to do this `git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` then `git fetch` then `git checkout pr/<TFS PR ID>` get the checksum from log `git log`. Now diff `git diff <log> <latest PR Checksum from merged branch>`